# CloudFlare causing GCP CloudRun and storage bucket to return 404 http code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, cloudflare, google-cloud-run

I was trying to host a simple Cloud Run application on Google Cloud Platform with Cloudflare in front of it. I kept getting 404s on all pages so gave up and switched to using buckets because it's a simple static website.

Cloudflare is pointing to the load balancer static external IP address.

I'm now encountering the exact same issue. I have a load balancer pointing to a GCP bucket with static content. With Cloudflare on, it serves up a 404 error for all pages. With Cloudflare off, it works fine.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you share your routing parameter in your HTTPS load balancer? Does the default path of your Load Balancer work with CloudFlare ON? And do you know with which host header CloudFlare present the requests?

Comment: What is the CloudFlare SSL/TLS encryption mode?

Comment: Thanks @john I didn't have full SSL on, fixed now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed full SSL turned on at Cloudflare's end

Answer (score 1):

To prevent getting 404s when Cloud Run is behind Cloudflare, you need to either create a "Domain Mapping" on Cloud Run with the domain you use (so that Host headers match), or you need to use Host Header Rewrite feature in Cloudflare Page Rules (might be a pro/enterprise feature) to set the header to Run service's *.run.app url.

In either case, see the note [on this page](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains), that is:

> For example, if you are using Cloudflare CDN, you should turn off the "Always use https" option in the "Edge Certificates" tab of the SSL/TLS tab.